# Is it possible to send a message to specific instance behind the ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using aws classic load balancer and I want to send a message to specific instance behind the ELB. I found some other questions in which they are trying to broadcast a message to all instances but in my case I want to send the message to selective instance based on some identifier like IP, Name etc.

Let me explain the scenario for better understanding.

Say there are two instances behind ELB i.e. instance1 and instance2. In a particular case when request is received from instance1 then I want to send a response to instance1 in a separate request. Similar applies to instance2 as well.

Is it possible to do it?

Edit 1:
I am trying to do this as I am using SignalR to broadcast a message to the client and waiting for the response from the client. If the response goes to another instance then the waiting instance will not get the response.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dictate to which server a request is sent. However, you can [Configure Sticky Sessions for Your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html), which enables the load balancer to bind a user's session to a specific instance. This ensures that all requests from the user during the session are sent to the same instance.

Basically, it uses a cookie to remember which server was used and will send future requests to the same server. That should probably meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John, I will read about Sticky sessions. While searching more in this regard I found that there is flexibility in Application Load balancer to define listener rules. Will that be the direction to explore if we will not choose to bind complete user session to a specific instance?

Comment: Application Load Balancer _Target Groups_ are used to direct traffic to sub-groups of servers, based upon the URL. For example, sending authentication requests to one set of servers and data requests to another, all through the same load balancer. You could create a Target Group of size 1, then send the requests with the configured URL and that would always go to one server, but this sounds like a strange thing to be doing for an application. Feel free to Edit your question to provide details of _WHY_ you wish to do this, and we might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: as @JohnRotenstein mention do host based routing it your ALP for login.com point  instance 1 and signup.com will point instnace 2. so the traffic will route based on DNS accordingly

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: You can't (?) use an ELB to "broadcast" to clients. ELB is designed to accept _incoming_ requests, route them to an EC2 instance, then provide the response. The instances cannot initiate the connection. If you are talking about keeping a long-connection open via Websockets, consider a [Network Load Balancer]([Listeners for Your Network Load Balancers - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-listeners.html)).